# Sending SMS - IntelliSMS - fopen Exception

Tags: zend-framework, sms, sms-gateway

I am trying to send a sms from my Controller in Zend - PHP.  I use IntelliSMS and I have exception in its library :/
The exception:

```
    exception 'Exception' with message 'Problem making HTTP request
https://www.intellisoftware.co.uk/smsgateway/sendmsg.aspx, fopen(https://www.intellisoftware.co.uk/smsgateway/sendmsg.aspx) 
[function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Story\library\IntelliSMS\SendScripts\IntelliSMS.php:302 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Story\library\IntelliSMS\SendScripts\IntelliSMS.php(199): IntelliSMS-
>MakeHTTPFormPost('https://www.int...', 'username=canib&...', 'Content-Type: a...') #1...
```

It is strange because I can send this sms by: Get method:

```
http://www.intellisoftware.co.uk/smsgateway/sendmsg.aspx?username=MyUsername &password=MyPassword&to=44771012345,44771054321&text=TheMessage
```

But I can not using this php Intellisms library. 
Do You have any idea? Do You know how to send Post Request using Zend framework?
I have tried:

```
     $request->getResponse()->setRedirect('http://www.intellisoftware.co.uk/smsgateway/sendmsg.aspx?
username=xxx&password=xxx&to='.$number.'&text='.$text,302);
```

But nothing happen :/

Thanks,

I have in my php.ini:
allow_url_fopen = On

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.
Probably I didnt set one property that was why it wasnt working.
Sorry for it, I dont know where exactly was mistake, I wrote it once again, set one property more and now it is working.